# Flutter Bloc - mapEventToState executes only once

Tags: flutter, bloc

Good day guys,

I am new to flutter. I'm trying simple state management using Bloc. I have a home screen which show/hides some widgets depending on the state. On a separate screen I have two buttons that add events to the stream which updates the state and then the widgets on the home screen react to the state updates. Its working fine but the UI only re-builds after the first event and on subsequent events the bloc yields the state but the UI does not update. Also in main.dart Material App is wrapped with MultBlocProvider. I'm from South Africa so I might not be able to immediately reply bc of timezones but any help will be hugely appreciated. Below are the code snippets.

**auth_state.dart**

```
class AuthState {
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
}
```

**auth_event.dart**

```
enum EventType { login, logout }

class AuthEvent {
  late EventType eventType;

  AuthEvent.login() {
    this.eventType = EventType.login;
  }

  AuthEvent.logout() {
    this.eventType = EventType.logout;
  }
}
```

**auth_bloc.dart**

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc(AuthState initialState) : super(initialState);

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    switch (event.eventType) {
      case EventType.login:
        AuthState newState = state;
        newState.isLoggedIn = true;
        yield newState;
        break;
      case EventType.logout:
        AuthState newState = state;
        newState.isLoggedIn = false;
        yield newState;
        break;
      default:
        throw Exception('Event not found $event');
    }
  }
}
```

**home_page.dart (snippet) -> bloc comsumer**

```
 Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
   child: BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
     listener: (context, state) {},
     builder: (context, state) {
       return Visibility(
         visible: state.isLoggedIn,
         child: IconButton(
           key: HomePage.navigateToNotifications,
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) => Notifications()),
             );
           },
           icon: Icon(Icons.circle_notifications,
             size: 50, color: HexColor('27B88D'))),
       );
     }))
```

**test_page.dart (snippet) -> fire bloc events**

```
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(AuthEvent.login()),
              child: Text('Log User in')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(AuthEvent.logout()),
              child: Text('Log User out'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find its easier just to declare separate state classes for states rather than new instances of the same state.

```
abstract class AuthState {}

class NotLoggedIn extends AuthState {}

class LoggedIn extends AuthState {}
```

Then your `mapEventToState` looks like this

```
  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    switch (event.eventType) {
      case EventType.login:
        {
          yield LoggedIn();
          break;
        }

      case EventType.logout:
        {
          yield NotLoggedIn();
          break;
        }

      default:
        throw Exception('Event not found $event');
    }
  }
```

Then your `BlocConsumer` looks like this and it rebuilds as you expect

```
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
              child: BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                listener: (context, state) {},
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Visibility(
                    visible: state is LoggedIn ? true : false,
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.circle_notifications,
                            size: 50, color: Colors.amber)),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Cool thanks man, you answer helped and it now works perfectly. Is bloc the desired pattern for state management in flutter and as a newbie am I on the right track ?

Comment: No problem. Best state management can be a loaded question because there's so much discussion/arguments about it. You definitely cannot go wrong with Bloc and if you can wrap your head around how that works then you'll probably find the rest of them a bit easier. My personal preferred is GetX, but again, Bloc is great. I do recommend updating Bloc to the latest version because it has been updated with an easier syntax.